# How to define resources AND a MergeDictionary with a key in a SL4 page

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, styles

This is probably a really stupid question but I can't figure this out.

I have a page with a MergeDictionary defined:

```
  <navigation:Page.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="../Assets/TourneySetupStyles.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </navigation:Page.Resources>
```

and I reference the styles in TourneySetupStyles.xaml in my XAML like this with no problem:

```
<TextBlock Text="Tourney Name:" Style="{StaticResource TourneySetupTextStyle}" />
```

However, now I need to add another page resource like this:

But the designer now throws a warning:
"The designer does not support loading dictionaries that mix 'ResourceDictionary' items without a key and other items in the same collection. Please ensure that the 'Resources' property does not contain 'ResourceDictionary' items without a key, or that the 'ResourceDictionary' item is the only element in the collection."

So I add a key to my ResourceDictionary like this:

```
   <navigation:Page.Resources>
         <local:Tournament x:Key="tournament" />
        <ResourceDictionary x:Key="whatever">
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="../Assets/TourneySetupStyles.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>

    </navigation:Page.Resources>
```

and the warning goes away. BUT now my reference to the style in TourneySetupStyles no longer works:

"Cannot find a Resource with the Name/Key TourneySetupTextStyle"

So I guess the question is: How do I access the style now that the ResourceDictionary is keyed?

Comment: Thanks! I got the same error (in WPF) and your solution works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*sigh* it seems that the order of the declarations is important, as soon as I move the first resource down it now works:

```
<navigation:Page.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary x:Key="TourneySetupStyles">
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="../Assets/TourneySetupStyles.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    <local:Tournament x:Key="tourneySetupViewModel" />
</navigation:Page.Resources>
```

If anyone can explain why it would be great for future reference...

Answer (score 8):

I just ran into this today -- I'm cross compiling to WPF / Silverlight.
Put the local resource inside the ResourceDictionary node, don't put a x:Key on the ResourceDictionary node.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/mydll;component/folder/MyResDict.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="OrangeGradient"
                             EndPoint="0.5,1"
                             MappingMode="RelativeToBoundingBox"
                             StartPoint="0.5,0">
            <LinearGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                <RotateTransform  CenterY="0.5"
                                  CenterX="0.5" />
            </LinearGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
            <GradientStop Color="#FFF3801E" />
            <GradientStop Color="#FFEDB17E"
                          Offset="0.5" />
            <GradientStop Color="#FFF3801E"
                          Offset="1" />
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

I can't explain why - but I know it works...

hth

Comment: Oh no... but I gave up on the designers in VS and Blend about 2 weeks after I started writing cross-compiled code. They simply do not work.

Comment: If I want to use the designers, I use a separate WPF or Silverlight only project, do my design work, then bring it to my "real" project and figure out how to get it to cross-compile. Getting the design to load in the designer after that is close to impossible.
I have open an open connect issue which is being worked by MS, but it isn’t really going anywhere.

Comment: This solution worked for me for a similar problem. I put a `ResourceDictionary` within a `Page.Resources`, and got the error `The property "Resources" can only be set once.`. I nearly gave up on it, and moved the resources to the application (which worked), but then I found this. All I had to do was move the `</ResourcedDictionary>` past all the other definitions in the resources, so that it was the last line before `</Page.Resources>`.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same problem.

I resolved the issue be defining my dictionary merges within the xaml file of the application instead of the view itself.

Ex:

```
    <ResourceDictionary>

        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources\Brushes\Brushes_Dictionary.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources\Storyboards\Storyboard_Dictionary.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

    </ResourceDictionary>

</Application.Resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I've just been bitten by this. As soon as Silverlight loads the merged resource dictionary, it deletes all local resources you've already added! In my case I need to programmatically add a resource before the InitalizeComponent() call, but since the UserControl includes a merged ResourceDictionary that resource is lost. IMHO this is a bug in Silverlight.

But putting local resources after the ResourceDictionary will work for cases like yours so I've up voted it.